# php project working on local host server but not working in live server

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

this project working well in localhost server but not working in live server when page opening without displaying login page its goinig to index.php?=home page and there so options not available & please help me out this problem.
And also i have added this live server link below please check it.I think i have included enough code for this project.I can't understand how this project working in localhost server.If any code problem it will not work even in local host server

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']))
header("location:index.php?page=home");

$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM system_settings limit 1")->fetch_array();
        foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
            if(!is_numeric($key))
                $_SESSION['setting_'.$key] = $value;
        }
?>

<script>
    $('#login-form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $('#login-form button[type="button"]').attr('disabled',true).html('Logging in...');
        if($(this).find('.alert-danger').length > 0 )
            $(this).find('.alert-danger').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax.php?action=login',
            method:'POST',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            error:err=>{
                console.log(err)
        $('#login-form button[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled').html('Login');

            },
            success:function(resp){
                if(resp == 1){
                    location.href ='index.php?page=home';
                }else if(resp == 2){
                    location.href ='voting.php';
                }else{
                    $('#login-form').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger">Username or password is incorrect.</div>')
                    $('#login-form button[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled').html('Login');
                }
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

[Check on live server][1]

Comment: seems ok to me?

Comment: not actually...after log in so many options missing in left side nav bar...if you click manage then error will be occured